# Need JQuery Functions to Load Several Sequential Actions From PHP

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

I have a main-page.php with a simple form (id=search) that performs a live search in a MySQL database and returns results in a list like this:

```
    echo "<ul style=\"list-style-type: none;\">";
      while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)) {
        echo "<li><a href=next-step.php?NDB_No=".$row['NDB_No'].">".$row['Long_Desc']."</a>";
    }
    echo "</ul>";
```

What I need is a JQuery function to allow me to click on any of the returned list items from the above list, but instead of being directed to next-step.php, I would like to stay on main-page.php, and have the div "results" on this page updated with the contents of the next-step.php script.

Of note, next-step.php performs another SQL search and returns results as a form element with radio buttons that are built with an echo command - something like this:

```
echo "<form id=choices>"
while ($line = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
echo "<input type=RADIO name=\"food_quantity\" value=\"$line[Gm_Wgt]\">";
echo "<b>$line[Amount] $line[Msre_Desc]</b> ($line[Gm_Wgt] grams)";
}
echo "<INPUT type=RADIO name=quantity>";
echo "<INPUT type=text NAME=my_quantity SIZE=4 value=\"\"> <b>grams</b>";
echo "<input type=submit name=Submit value=\"Submit\">";
echo "</form>";
```

Finally, what I'd like to be able to do with the form "choices" is to check a radio button option, send the selection to an external php page (let's call it last.php), where yet another SQL search is performed, the results of which should then be returned as a blcok of formatted HTML into the original "results" div of main-page.php.

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Well, Write the query and let us know where you stuck in that !

Comment: Well, I am stuck at "<a href=next-step.php?NDB_No=......" - I can't figure out how to write a function to load what next-step.php is returning into div "results" of main-page.php when I click on this link. It seems like I have to have the link in this format to be able to pass the NDB_No to next-step.php, but in doing so I am directed to this page, which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the simple and easy 4 steps that i would recommend you and you shall customize it to your need

**Step 1 :** Write a Jquery function onclick()

```
<script>
$( "#yourID" ).click(function() {
  $( this ).slideUp();
});
</script>
```

**Step 2 :**  Do an ajax call and send value to the Server

```
$.post( "yourServer.php", { data: "yourData" })
  .done(function( data ) {

  });
```

**Step 3 :** Get the value in server side

```
$data = $_POST['data'];
#Do some process and get the result
```

**Step 3 :** Send the Results

```
echo json_encode($yourData)
```

**Step 4 :** Get the results in JQuery success event & Show in the div that you need to update

```
if(success.data==1)
{
$('#yourResult').html(data.name);
}
else
{
$('#yourResult').html(data.error);
}
```

Hope this helps you !